# Get Items running repeat flows

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow

I have a Power Automate flow where I am trying to fix the following problem:

1 main SharePoint list where users log a request including location. A second list with a few location values. The flow needs to check if one of the location codes used by the user is on the second list and if so change the status.

I have written a flow that actually does that and works by getting the second list items and then a condition that compares the 2 list and if present changes the status.

The problem is that the flow keeps running repeatedly even if I am not modifying anything. Presume it is in some kind of loop but I haven't been able to solve that. Grateful for any ideas. I have added images of the flow below. Also shows run history seems to keep triggering twice.

Flow:

[image]

[image]

Run History:

[image]

Comment: If you are updating the same list using "Update item" action, then it is a expected behavior as you are using "When an item is created or modified" trigger.

Comment: OK thanks for the comment but if I turn the flow back on it keeps running even though I haven't made any further changes to the list so I don't get why that is.

Comment: Try using trigger conditions to avoid unnecessary flow runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are updating the same SharePoint list using "Update item" action, it is a expected behavior when you use "When an item is created or modified" trigger.

When you try to save such flow, it also shows you the warning related to this like:

[image]

To avoid infinite flow running, you can use **trigger conditions** in Power automate flows.

Check below links for more details about using trigger conditions in flow:

1. [Preventing an endless loop](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Preventing-an-endless-loop/td-p/685739)
2. [Avoid Infinite Loops In Power Automate](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/avoid-infinite-loops-in-power-automate/)